# How can I "save" a function?

Tags: save, persistence

If I create a function, for example:

```
f[list_] := 
 Total[list]!/Apply[Times, list]/
   Apply[Times, Map[Length, Split[list]]!]/
  EulerPhi[Apply[LCM, Apply[LCM, list]]]
```

Is there a way to save this function so that if I shut down Mathematica, I could return later and not have to re-create the function?

Comment: Have a look at [DumpSave](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DumpSave.html).

Comment: …or put the definition in `init.m`.

Comment: ... or put the definition in an initialization cell in your notebook.

Comment: … or use `LocalSymbol`.

Comment: @ b.gatessucks  OK  thank you everyone.  If you put your comment in the answer section I'll mark it as complete.